# C# Bootstrap Pagination in ASP.NET Gridview pager style?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm already done with Header, Item, and Footer but not Pager using Bootstrap 3.0

Could you please guide me how to implement Bootstrap pagination in ASP.NET Gridview pager style?

Please help!

Additional information:::

Here is what I have done so far by adding CssClass. The table display perfect with Bootstrap style applied.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <asp:GridView ID="grdSearchAgreement" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover"
            GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

And here is the Paging style that generated from ASP.NET GridView. It is table structure tr td.

```
<tr>
        <td colspan="7"><table>
            <tr>
                <td><span>1</span></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$body$grdSearchAgreement&#39;,&#39;Page$2&#39;)">2</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$body$grdSearchAgreement&#39;,&#39;Page$3&#39;)">3</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
```

But refer to Bootstrap 3.0 Pagination Document. The style can only apply to ul li. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#pagination

```
    <ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I change tr td pager that generate from gridview to ul li??

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I know this is old, But I found something, which is a css style, simple easy and fast

https://sufiawan.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/asp-net-use-bootstrap-pagination-on-gridview/

I hope it will save someone sometime.

---

update:

*In case the link is down:

You add the CSS

```
.pagination-ys {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td {
    display: inline;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > a,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #dd4814;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-decoration: none;    
    margin-left: -1px;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #aea79f;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    cursor: default;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:first-child > a,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:first-child > span {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:last-child > a,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td:last-child > span {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > a:hover,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span:hover,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > a:focus,
.pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span:focus {
    color: #97310e;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

And just use inside the grd

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" />
```

Comment: Great. For those who want to align the pager to right can add this in their css: `.pagination-ys > td:first-child {
                float: right;
            }`

Answer (score 13):

My answer is taken from previous answer by iYazee6
what's new here is enhancing css layout of pagination, implement it then display the result.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  CssClass="table table-striped table-hover"   OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Center" CssClass = "GridPager" />
...
```

css code:

```
.GridPager a,
.GridPager span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 9px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .8), 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    font-size: .875em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #717171;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 1);
}

.GridPager a {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #969696;
    border: 1px solid #969696;
}

.GridPager span {

    background: #616161;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .8);
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    border: 1px solid #3AC0F2;
}
```

the result is:

[image]

Comment: Nice one! I chose this answer

Answer (score 3):

Just slightly customize answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385838/dynamically-generate-page-linkbuttons-for-the-pagertemplate-of-a-gridview) and you have nice GridView pager that **support any Twitter Bootstrap CSS Theme**.

GridView template:

```html
<asp:GridView ... AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
  ...
  <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <PagerTemplate>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <asp:Repeater ID="Pager" ItemType="System.Int32" SelectMethod="GetPages" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <li class='<%#((int)Item == this.GridView.PageIndex+1)? "active" : "" %>'>
            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="<%# Item %>"
                Text="<%# Item %>" runat="server" OnClick="PageIndexChanging" />
          </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
  </PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Server-side code:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetPages()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, GridView.PageCount);
}

protected void PageIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton pageLink = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridView.PageIndex = Int32.Parse(pageLink.CommandArgument) - 1;

    BindDataToGridView();
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the simplest i believe

Comment: I agree, simplest answer and easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide PagerTemplate for GridView control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate.aspx

Comment: Please provide the relevant details from your links in your answer. Should those sites change or go down your answer is useless to anyone going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Bootsrap Pagination is static. You have to make it dynamic to add it to a gridview so that pager elements are generated according to the number of records in gridview. You need to write some jquery code to make it dynamic. Best way is to use one from the lot of jquery plugins available, for example [Bootpag](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.UnThA3BQF0w).

Here is a typical example of [how to use Bootstrap pagination in ASP.NET GridView](http://www.programming-free.com/2013/07/bootstrap-pagination-for-aspnet-gridview.html).

Comment: Please provide the relevant details from your links in your answer. Should those sites change or go down your answer is useless to anyone going forward.

Answer (score 1):

iYazee6 's result causing display issue in my grid. It's taking only first column of the grid to hold pager even the html is colspan="6" for a 6 column grid. I can't determine why.
Enhanced solution of GridPager css is great.
I have added some more css to use it like Bootstrap  i.e. GridPager-info OR GridPager-Danger OR GridPager-Success to change the colors accordingly.

CSS Snippet is:

```css
/***** GridPager-Danger *****/

.GridPager-Danger a,
.GridPager-Danger span {
    border: solid 1px #C60C30;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #717171;
    
}

.GridPager-Danger a {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #C60C30;
    border: 1px solid #C60C30;
}

.GridPager-Danger a:hover {
    background-color: #C60C30;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.GridPager-Danger span {
    background: #C60C30;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}



/***** GridPager-Success *****/

.GridPager-Success a,
.GridPager-Success span {
    border: solid 1px #3c763d;
    background: #eeffcc;
    color: #717171;
    
}

.GridPager-Success a {
    background-color: #eeffcc;
    color: #3c763d;
    border: 1px solid #3c763d;
}

.GridPager-Success a:hover {
    background-color: #3c763d;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.GridPager-Success span {
    background: #3c763d;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

You just need to copy this css along with GridPager css in GridPager.css file and add this code into your html

```html
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Center" CssClass="GridPager GridPager-Info" />

OR

<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Center" CssClass="GridPager GridPager-Success" />

OR

<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Center" CssClass="GridPager GridPager-Danger" />
```

It might help someone using Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Building on iYazee6 post above from Yusuf Setiawan's Blog.

I split out the a:hover and span:hover and increased the padding width to give it an effect on mouse over. The original padding: 8px 12px. Also made the font bold.

```
    .pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > a:hover,
    .pagination-ys table > tbody > tr > td > span:hover {
        padding: 8px 16px;
        color: #97310e;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        border-color: #dddddd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for bootstrap 4 rtl

add PagerStyle-CssClass="bs4-aspnet-pager"

```
/*bs4-aspnet-pager*/
.bs4-aspnet-pager a,
.bs4-aspnet-pager span {
position: relative;
float: right;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin-right: -1px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: ##007bff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.bs4-aspnet-pager span {
z-index: 3;
color: #fff;
cursor: default;
background-color: #007bff;
border-color: #007bff;
}

.bs4-aspnet-pager tr > td:first-child > a,
.bs4-aspnet-pager tr > td:first-child > span {
margin-right: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.bs4-aspnet-pager tr > td:last-child > a,
.bs4-aspnet-pager tr > td:last-child > span {
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.bs4-aspnet-pager a:hover,
.bs4-aspnet-pager span:hover,
.bs4-aspnet-pager a:focus,
.bs4-aspnet-pager span:focus {
z-index: 2;
color: #23527c;
background-color: #eee;
border-color: #ddd;
}

.bs4-aspnet-pager td {
padding: 0;
}
/*end bs4-aspnet-pager */
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Markup consists of an ASP.Net GridView. For the GridView I have enabled paging using the AllowPaging property and I have also specified on the OnPageIndexChanging event.

The code to bind the GridView with records from the Customers table of the Northwind database.

In order to style the GridView Pager you need to follow the following.

Next you need to assign the Pager CSS Class to the Page using the PagerStyle-CssClass property as shown below.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Right" CssClass = "GridPager" />
</asp:GridView>
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Right" CssClass = "GridPager" />


<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    .GridPager a, .GridPager span
    {
        display: block;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .GridPager a
    {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        color: #969696;
        border: 1px solid #969696;
    }
    .GridPager span
    {
        background-color: #A1DCF2;
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #3AC0F2;
    }
</style>
```